# function preg_match multiple urls

Tags: php, function, mobile, preg-match

Please help.

I think it only reads one of the preg_matches inside the function. What should i do?

> `function images($content) {
>       preg_match("#http://cdn1.image.site.com/[^\.]+\.jpg#",$content,$image);
>       preg_match("#http://cdn2.image.site.com/[^\.]+\.jpg#",$content,$image);
>       preg_match("#http://cdn3.image.site.com/[^\.]+\.jpg#",$content,$image);
>       preg_match("#http://cdn4.image.site.com/[^\.]+\.jpg#",$content,$image);
>       $result['image'] = $image[0];
>     return $result;
>   }`

Comment: [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) - **edit** - I might be missing the mark here as the answers are still returning a single image... But your function name is **images()** so I'd presume you want to return multiple images... you should use `preg_match_all("#http://cdn\d\.image\.site\.com/[^\.]+\.jpg#", $content, $images); return empty($images) ? array() : $images[0];`

Comment: each call to preg_match will over write the prevous' population of $image. use `$image[]` and see if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve added a few comments to your code in order to explain how it works:

```
function images($content) {
    preg_match("#http://cdn1.image.site.com/[^\.]+\.jpg#", $content, $image);
                                                        // $image is created
    preg_match("#http://cdn2.image.site.com/[^\.]+\.jpg#", $content, $image);
                                                        // $image is overwritten
    preg_match("#http://cdn3.image.site.com/[^\.]+\.jpg#", $content, $image);
                                                        // $image is overwritten
    preg_match("#http://cdn4.image.site.com/[^\.]+\.jpg#", $content, $image);
                                                        // $image is overwritten
    $result['image'] = $image[0];
    return $result;
}
```

Obviously you don’t want to create an array and overwrite it thrice! So you may create four different arrays, as in the following code:

```
function images($content) {
    preg_match("#http://cdn1.image.site.com/[^\.]+\.jpg#", $content, $image1);
    preg_match("#http://cdn2.image.site.com/[^\.]+\.jpg#", $content, $image2);
    preg_match("#http://cdn3.image.site.com/[^\.]+\.jpg#", $content, $image3);
    preg_match("#http://cdn4.image.site.com/[^\.]+\.jpg#", $content, $image4);
    $result['image'] = array($image1[0], $image2[0], $image3[0], $image4[0]);
    return $result;
}
```

But, because `preg_match` stops when the first match is found, your function will return at most four matches – the first one for `...cdn1...`, the second one for `...cdn2...`, the third one for `...cdn3...` and the fourth one for `...cdn4...`. You may spare yourself all the trouble simply by merging the four of them into one succinct regular expression `...cdn[1-4]...` and then use `preg_match_all` (which doesn’t have the one match limitation of `preg_match`):

```
function images($content){
    preg_match_all("#http://cdn[1-4].image.site.com/[^\.]+\.jpg#",$content,$image);
    $result['image'] = $image[0];
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each call to `preg_match` saves the results in `$image`. You only access `$image` once, so you only get the last value.

It seems like you want this, instead:

```
function images($content) {
    preg_match("#http://cdn\d\.image\.site\.com/[^\.]+\.jpg#",$content,$image);
    $result['image'] = $image[0];
    return $result;
}
```